# C++ function to chop very small numerical values

Tags: c++, floating-point

Is there a C++ function that chops very small numerical values that appear due to approximations of the floating point numbers in the CPU to zero? I want to use this in complex number calculation, so it can appear in either the real or imaginary parts.

Comment: @Paul R: There's a Mathematica function called `Chop` that will zero any number less than `10^-15` or so.

Comment: @Mystical: yes I need this Mathematica function in c++

Comment: That should be trivial to implement yourself, no ?

Comment: As my answer says, no such function exists. But you can trivially write one if you already have a bounds in mind. (like `10^-15`)

Answer (score 6):

No such function exists. The problem is that "small" is relative. If you're working on very large numbers, `1.0` can be considered small enough to chop. Similarly, if you're working with small numbers, `10^-30` could still be considered significant.